# Loading data from GCS to BigQuery using Wildcards and Autodetect

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

New to posting on StackOverflow.

Using the google.cloud.bigquery python SDK, I have been trying to work up a solution to load data from GCS to BigQuery without defining a table schema.

My `LoadJobConfig`'s autodetect is set to True and I am using a wildcard (*) in the GCS URI.

I have confirmed that `Autodetect` works with wildcards but the load job fails because the data source that I am working with will usually autodetect a specific column to be a float (e.g. 0.30) but sometimes adds operator symbols (e.g. < 0.10) and thus needs to be a string.

Can anyone think of a solution without having to define the schema? Here's my `LoadJobConfig` that I've passed to `bigquery.client.Client`'s `load_table_from_uri` method.

```
source_uri = 'gs://%s/%s/%s/*' % (source, report_type, date)
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED'
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
job_config.source_format = 'CSV'
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
job_config.autodetect = True
job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(source_uri, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
job.result()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data seems to be broken in some part.

I would suggest to use flag: `--max_bad_records`  which skips broken records.

For details please look here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bigquery-import-gcs-file-python

Comment: Adding `--max_bad_records` fixes my problem. The only concern I have with this might be that if there's any bad entries, my `LoadJobConfig` might not be strict enough. Will use this as my solution for now though, thanks a lot.